# How to use Steam (OpenId) to login into my Firebase powered Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, openid, steam

I'm building a Flutter app and I want users to be able to login through Steam ([OpenId](https://steamcommunity.com/dev)).
The app is powered by Firebase.

I'm pretty new to the whole OpenId world and I've read into it but I'm still not getting it.

I found that Firebase Supports [signinWithCustomToken](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCustomToken.html) so I think I should get the Steam OpenId to get me one of those.
I also found two packages which might help me but I couldn't get those to work either:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client
2. https://pub.dev/packages/steam_login

If tried the following sample from the `openid_client` package:

```
_authenticate(Uri uri, String clientId, List<String> scopes) async {
    try {
      var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
      var client = Client(issuer, clientId);

      print('CLAIMS:');
      print(issuer.claimsMap);

      urlLauncher(String url) async {
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }

      var authenticator = Authenticator(client,
          scopes: scopes, port: 4000, urlLancher: urlLauncher);

      var c = await authenticator.authorize();

      closeWebView();

      print(await c.getUserInfo());
    }catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

But I have no idea what to give as the `uri`, `clientId` and `scopes`.
For the `uri` I've tried `https://steamcommunity.com/openid` but when I try this I'm getting an error that it tried to Json.parse a xml response.

I've also tried the example for the `steam_login` package [here](https://github.com/Hexer10/steam_login/blob/master/example/steam_login_example.dart), but that does nothing and doesn't feel like it should work within a Flutter app (even though the package states it Flutter compatible).

So if anybody could explain to me how I could achieve this with a working sample that would be great.
If I get this to work I'm planning on creating a tutorial/guide for it for others.